# Undergo vs Suffer an accident

Tags: differences, vocabulary, semantics, collocation

I was doing a CAE Practice Test on Use of English (It is a multiple choice exercise) when I came across the following example:

> Her life was cut tragically short. She ______ a horrific accident at
>   the National Air Show in Ohio in the USA, when her plane crashed
>   through the roof of a building

In the gap you need to choose between **underwent** and **suffered**.

Both of these collocate with **accident** according to ***ludwig.guru***: 1) [suffered](https://ludwig.guru/s/suffer+%2B+accident), 2. [underwent](https://ludwig.guru/s/undergo+%2B+accident)

However, the answer key suggests **suffered** as the only possibility.

Why can't the latter work as well?

Comment: With _underwent_, the first two sentences on Ludwig.guru are the same source and same sentence. From the _New Yorker_: _All she had to do was undergo a terrible accident._ It's probably a joke - hard to tell without context - but it's not normal. The rest are clearly different and more remote as collocations. (For one, you might well _undergo_ surgery as a result of an _accident._) I'd try a dictionary first, if I were you; it's more likely to give you a precise answer.

Comment: You ordinarily choose to undergo something, whereas you normally would choose to avoid suffering something if you could.

Comment: [These Google 4-grams {suffered a terrible accident,underwent a terrible accident}](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=suffered+a+terrible+accident%2Cunderwent+a+terrible+accident&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csuffered%20a%20terrible%20accident%3B%2Cc0) more faithfully show collocation strength here. 'Underwent' is non-standard or close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference here is one of [*affect*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/affect), which used as a noun is a psychological term for "the emotion associated with an idea or set of ideas."

One can *undergo* any process, including an accident, but the tenor of the example makes it clear that whoever is relating the tale has a distinct opinion about it. The pilot's accident was a catastrophe (her life was cut "tragically short," the accident was "horrific"), and so the neutral verb *underwent* might seem out of place, or even somewhat comical, in that sentence. Coupling "tragically" and "horrific" with "suffered" creates a concordance that reinforces the notion that the accident was a very bad thing.

Comment: If correct, this can't be the whole story. 'She _had_ a terrible accident' is also idiomatic. It's the associations with a drawn-out process and to an extent optionality in my opinion (but the ludicrous _is_ a factor).